# avoid getting duplicate matches from join

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following query with a simple join. 
For each row in table_A there are several rows that matches in table_B. I only want to get one of those matches (it doesn't matter which one). How do I do that?

```
SELECT a.id, b.something
FROM table_A a
  LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.Id = b.something
```

I am using teradata.

Comment: you haven't given us much to work with here.. According to your "query"  `a.id` and `b.something` would be the exact same value so why even join to `table_B`.. It would be helpful if you gave a little more detail or actual SQL

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your results are displaying exact duplicates in every column you can simply add DISTINCT to your select clause as well

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, b.something FROM table_A a LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.Id = b.something
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `GROUP BY` like below you'll only get one row for each a.id:

```
SELECT a.id, max(b.something)
FROM table_A a
  LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.Id = b.something
group by a.id
```

Comment: what if b.something isn't part of the SELECT?

Comment: What do you mean? Is there no column something in the B table? Or no B table at all? Also, is it the same b.something in the select-list as in the ON clause?

Comment: Imagine this: "SEL a.id FROM a INNER JOIN b on a.id=b.something" In case there is more than one match I still only want to get one row. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think a bit more info on the table schemas would help. I can think of several different ways to do this depending on the structure of the tables and the relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `sample` :

```
SELECT a.id, b.something
FROM table_A a
LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.Id = b.something
GROUP BY a.id
SAMPLE 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

To your query